# Can we have leading zeroes in hexadecimal constants?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, constants, compile-time-constant

I am using C and Assembler on different platforms as well as VB.net for .NET development on Windows. In VB.net, when having long lists of constants or enums, I find it particularly annoying that the IDE does not seem to allow leading zeroes in hexadecimal constants; it just removes them automatically.

For example, in VS 2010, in a VB.net project's source file, if I type

```
public const foo as uinteger = &H00000012
```

it converts this to

```
Public Const foo As UInteger = &H12
```

as soon as I the cursor leaves the respective source code line.

Is there a method to prevent the removal of the leading zeroes? I am happy with the other "auto corrections", though.

Comment: You could probably do it by turning of Pretty Listing in the IDE options, but you'd then lose all the rest of the auto-formatting that the code editor provides.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I don't want to lose the other auto-formatting, so I think I'll live with it. Nevertheless, plus 1 ... I already suspected that there is no satisfying solution.